# coffeescript variable to form value

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

Ok, so I have this inside a form

```
<INPUT type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Write" onClick="writeText(this.form)">
```

and I have the following generated javascript from coffeescript

```
(function() {
  var writeText;

  writeText = function(form) {
    return form.inputbox.value = "ping";
  };

}).call(this);
```

I need to know how do I call writeText?

as it is when I click the button nothing happens....if I remove the function(){}.call(this) wrapper it works.

I cannot remove the wrapper. I need to know how to call writeText with the .call(this) in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a scoping issue, where Coffeescript wraps everything inside it's own closure to avoid polluting the global namespace. There are two solutions;

1. Compile using coffeescript's "--bare" option (which avoid putting the wrapper there in the first place).
2. Bind your coffeescript function to some object that the browser sees when running. Like this:

`window.writeText = (form) ->
  form.inputbox.value = "ping"`

In the second option, your writeText function is bound to the window object in the browser, which is the implicit `this` object when your script runs in the browser.

Comment: That was it "window.writeText" Thanks a million!